# Can I make a autonomous Hamiltonian diffeomorphism into a non-autonomous one?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, diffeomorphism

Let $H:R^{2n}\to R$ be an autonomous Hamiltonian such that the only constant $1$-periodic orbit is the origin and let $\varphi_H^1$ be the time $1$ map of the flow of it Hamiltonian vector field. Is it possible to find a time dependent Hamiltonian $K_t$ (where the dependence of time ir non-trivial) such that $\varphi_H^1 = \varphi_{K_t}^1$?

Comment: Every autonomous Hamiltonian is also a non-autonomous Hamiltonian, so it's not clear what exactly are you asking. Do you want $K_t$ to be non-trivially time-dependent?

Comment: Yes @ReiHenigman, exactly that. I would like $K_t$ to be non-trivially time-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following exercise [1.4.A from the (great) book "The geometry of the group of symplectic diffeomorphisms" by Leonid Polterovich]:

Reparametrization of flows: Let $f_t, t \in [0, a]$
be a Hamiltonian flow generated by a normalized Hamiltonian $F (x, t)$.
Show that $f_{at}, t \in [0, 1]$ is again a Hamiltonian flow generated by
$aF (x, at)$. Therefore every Hamiltonian diffeomorphism is in fact a
time-one map of some Hamiltonian flow. More generally, show that for
every smooth function $b(t)$ with $b(0) = 0$ the flow $f_{b(t)}$ is a Hamiltonian flow whose normalized Hamiltonian equals $\frac{db}{dt}(t)F (x, b(t))$.

Comment: Hi @ReiHenigman. Right. I think I got what you mean. Please, let me know  if it was this: If $b(t)$ is a smooth function with $b(0) =0$, $b(1) =1$ and the first derivative is non-trivially dependet of $t$, then $\varphi^t_H = \varphi_{K_t}^{b(t)}$ with $K(t,x)= \frac{db} {dt}(t)H(x)$. So, another question, Does this mean that the Hamiltonian diffeo generated by the time-dependent Hamiltonian will also have non-isolated fixed points?

Comment: Yes, exactly.
Regarding your second question - $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a fixed point of $H$ if and only if it's a fixed point of $K_t$ (for a smooth positive $b(t)$). So It wouldn't change the sets of isolated fixed points / non-isolated fixed points. Not sure if I answered your question.